# Selection not populating to email generation

Tags: php, email

I'm helping a friend with a site.  They have their customers select a product to reserve.  When the end user selects the product, the field is populated to them.  They submit the form and an email is sent to the business.  All fields seem to pick up on the email, except for the product selected.  In the php file to create the email, the products are listed like this:

```
<?php 

 if ($_POST['equipment'] == "001")     $equipment = "Seat1";

 if ($_POST['equipment'] == "002")     $equipment = "Seat2";

 if ($_POST['equipment'] == "003")     $equipment = "Seat3";     

 if ($_POST['equipment'] == "004")     $equipment = "Seat4";
```

Then in the generate email section it says:

```
$message .="<tr><td>Seat Number</td><td>".$equipment." </td></tr>";
```

Other fields such as name, phone, email and amount all list correctly on the email, just not this option. I have very little experience in PHP.

Comment: So the problem is of not getting correct value or not getting the value at all ?

Comment: post the HTML for this

Comment: @zenwraight Not getting a value at all

Comment: Hi Fred, sorry I was responding to the first question.  The HTML for the page?  All I have is the two different php forms.  I will have to ask my friend for the other files, I just want to make sure I ask for the correct info

Comment: Use php's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php see if anything comes of it, such as an `undefined index` notice. If you're trying to get that from a 2nd form, then that stands to be out of scope from the first form. Without full code, it makes it next to impossible to give you a concrete solution. Chances are it's an out of scope, or the element is not named.

Comment: Thank you Fred I will try your suggesting and see what I can figure out.  I know they use Wordpress for their site and the code was from a file called z_reserve.php and on the Wordpress page they have an iframe that calls to that file.  I appreciate your help, i'm learning as I'm going so please excuse me for not understanding exactly

Comment: For debugging it can also help to use F12 in a browser, record the traffic, and see what is actually being posted.  Perhaps the field name doesn't match because of a typo.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Dave S

Comment: Sorry to ask this question, but I really can't find the answer.  When looking over the code I have above, each line is of course similar.  I was just trying different stuff and when I deleted one of the = signs so there was only one, if I selected that option it was carried to the email that was generated.  So I though, have only 1 equal sign for each line, but all that did was insert the very last line's selection into the email.  Does anyone know exactly how I would code each line to select whichever is chosen?  If someone can help, I can email you the code Thank  You